# Motorized webcam which can look up, down, left, right with its own application?

Tags: webcam

The title may seem a bit misleading as I was not sure what the term is.

I am looking for a webcam that can turn itself for instance I want it to look to the right or left sides, up or down, so by using the webcam application it will move without the need of me manually moving it.

The other requirement would be for it to have movement sensor.

I currently have a lifecam which I had made a custom motor + hardware to do this for me so with my own piece of software I can freely make it turn left, right, up, down however I've been curious if besides those IP and security cams there is a webcam with such capabilities or what would be the best IP / security cam that fits this requirements?

*I guess it would be a motorized webcam or webcam with motorized tripod however some how they need a connection so that the tripod responds to the commands sent to the webcam.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a PTZ (pan,tilt, zoom) camera with motion sensing. There are many on market in wide range of price (A search will show you $33 to hundreds of dollars) and functions (IR/night vision, and so on). Primarily these are wireless IP cameras typically for security, but I imagine they would work well as a web cam with some tweaking on focus and placement.

This is one for about $47 US [DGGate.com](http://www.dhgate.com/product/dhgate/152119782.html?utm_source=pla&utm_medium=GMC&utm_campaign=cecilia&utm_term=152119782&f=bm%7C152119782%7C007003-CCTVProducts%7CGMC%7CAdwords%7Cpla%7Ccecilia%7CUS%7C007003001-CCTVCamera%7Cc%7C&gclid=CJfBld-I_LgCFQai4Aod_VcAjA). I have not used it or endorse it, but it may help you on your search and what is available.

[image: ip]

Comment: Pretty good, will check on that, the terms you've mentioned were really missing on my searches :)

Answer (score 3):

I use a Foscam for what you have described.  It's definately not the only option out there but it's one of the cheapest and I believe it fits all your stated requirements.  My only complaints about it is that the resolution is pretty low.  Getting a higher resolution camera that pan's and tilts is usually out of my price range but might be useful to you depending on your specific application.

One thing I do love about this camera is it's easy ability to mount to the ceiling and invert the image, my boss has one as a baby monitor also.  They are good little cameras and surprisingly affordable.

[Foscam website](http://foscam.us/)

[Foscam on Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1R20TH9396)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out while price is not much of a concern I am surely looking into quality, durability among other terms.